# pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, pyinstaller

when i tried to use command pyinstaller main.py --onefile in terminal it shows *pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*
i also tried to reinstall pyinstaller[enter image des[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGdea.png)cription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltswq.png)

i want to fix this problem

Comment: Please search this site for the exact message **not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file** that you included in your title. This question has been asked (and answered) here literally hundreds of times before - surely one of those existing answers can help you solve this issue.